# Command argument from desktop file ignored in gnome3

Tags: gnome, display-resolution, .desktop

I'm trying to workaround a bug that makes Spotify client ignore HiDPI  scaling settings. I discovered that launching it with a command

```
spotify --force-device-scale-factor=1.5
```

does the job. So, I tried to modify the .desktop file that launches app. I have two copies located in

```
/usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop
/usr/share/spotify/spotify.desktop
```

I tried modifying both of them so that they are

```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Spotify
  GenericName=Music Player
  Comment=Spotify streaming music client
  Icon=spotify-client
  Exec=spotify --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 %U
  TryExec=spotify
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Categories=Audio;Music;Player;AudioVideo;
  MimeType=x-scheme-handler/spotify;
```

but still launching from gnome menu gives utterly small, unscaled fonts (opened directly with '--force-device-scale-factor=1.5, right launched from menu)
[image: left: opened directly with '--force-device-scale-factor=1.5, right launched from menu]
I tried quoting argument inspired by [this documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html), but with no result. Can someone clarify what am I doing wrong?

My system is Ubuntu 16.04, gnome version 3.18.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `spotify` to the full path to `spotify` in the `Exec=` line, i.e. change

```
Exec=spotify --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 %U
```

to

```
Exec=/full/path/to/spotify --force-device-scale-factor=1.5 %U
```

To find out the full path to `spotify` you may run

```
whereis spotify
```

or

```
which spotify
```

It should be something like `/usr/bin/spotify`.